# Cannot find symbol - method count(java.lang.string)

Tags: java, string, methods, count, lang

I trying to make a word count program without having to use split(). 
Okay, before you guys tell me off saying this is a duplicate. I **know**.
the other solution wasn't very specific to me as they were using the add method.

```
public static void findWord()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
    String sentence = input.nextLine();
    int numOfWords = count(sentence);
```

here count comes up as an error.

```
    System.out.println("input: " + sentence);
    System.out.println("number of words: " + numOfWords);
}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?  Please provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stefan mentioned, you are missing a `count` method (as that is what you trying to call when you say `count(sentence);`)

Slightly different answer here as you asked not to use `split()`

```
public static int count(String s) {
        int count = 1; //to include the first word
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

A better way to do it, if spaces is an issue is:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sentence);
System.out.println(st.countTokens());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `count` method. This is a simple example:

```
public int count(String sentence) {
    return sentense.split(" ").length;
}
```

`sentense.split(" ")` will split the `sentence` where there are blank space, and return an array of `Strings` (`"hello world"` becomes `{"hello", "world"}`).

`.length` will return the number of items in the array, which in this case is the number of words.